# Automagically populate DB fields (like created, modified do)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In CakePHP if you add `created` or `modified` fields to any DB table, then when data is saved or updated it inserts the DATETIME into the fields respectively.

I want to add to this.

I have a function in `core.php` (app/config/core.php) called `isCheap()` and can be called anywhere. This function returns either TRUE or FALSE.

I want to extend MODEL so that if any table has an `is_cheap TINYINT(1)` field it automatically get saved to the value of isCheap().

I looked at the file `cake/libs/model/model.php` and in the save() function there are many references to `created`, `modified`, `updated`. I am pretty sure this is where it does its magic but the function has a lot going on in it, and I am not sure how I could extend it to add my behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the core. Instead, just add a beforeSave callback to app_model.php in the application. All models inherit from this class.

It would look something like this:

```
function beforeSave() {
    if(isset($this->_schema['is_cheap'])) {
        // your update here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**cdburgess**'s answer is what led me to my fix. For completness I want to add here exactly what I did.

I created the file `/app/app_model.php` with this as the contents:

```
class AppModel extends Model 
{
    function beforeSave()
    {
        if(isset($this->_schema['is_cheap'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['is_cheap'] = isCheap() ? 1 : 0;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I added the `? 1 : 0;` becuase I am not sure if the TRUE/FALSE will automatically be converted to integers.

Works great, thanks cdburgess.

Comment: Glad to help. I am glad to see that it worked as you would expect too. ;)